# How to edit the Response object in an CXF out Interceptor?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I am working on an **Out interceptor** on my **Rest** service and I want to retrieve the `Response` object from the message, edit it and then put it back to the message of the interceptor.

I have tried

```
message.getExchange().get(Response.class);
```

and

```
message.get(Response.class);
```

but I get back `null`. My out interceptor is set in `SEND` phase.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure it is useful, but you can get the HttpServletResponse using `HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)message.getExchange()             .getInMessage().get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_RESPONSE);`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think you are better off with a CXF filter.

Comment: I am trying filters but I am facing a NoSuchMethodError. Have a look in my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22910580/2105307)